# Coldfusion GetComponentMetaData functions order

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

The functions list returned by GetComponentMetaData seems to be ordered randomly. Is there any way to get the proper order of functions as defined in the cfc? Thanks.

Comment: What's your use case? The method names are probably returned in alphabetical order, and it's unlikely that order can be changed.

Comment: @SOS I'm thinking of controlling all menu items based on annotations in controller/handler cfcs (one menu item per function in the cfc). I want to be able to order the menu items based simply on the order of the underlying functions in the cfc and avoid having to specify another annotation for order, but I guess I'll just have to do it.